# sql function to query a Table based on searching a column for a substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

I googled this but couldn't find an easy answer:

I need to write a function that takes a substring as parameter and return those rows which have this substring in a certain column:

```
select * from myTable where myTable.someColumn contains @substring
```

appreciate your help
thank you

Answer (score 1):

you may use 
`where myTable.someColumn like '%?%'`
with '@substring' as parameter.

Comment: I need a more precise answer like `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` as I need to store this function in my db and call it from my C++ application.

Comment: Can't help you with postgres.